What is the issue behind the error "Invalid Key Length" or "Bad Decrypt error" while decrypting SEK which is used to generate IRN for e-invoice?
I am trying to decrypt the session encryption key generated using AES 256(AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding)
algorithm which is encrypted () with AppKey. But I am facing Invalid length error or bad decrypt error.

The first step was to call the authentication API for which the payload was username, password, appkey and forcerefreshtoken for which the response data involved Authtoken, sek, etc...

As per requirement[AppKeyAny 32 character random unique id generated by user, identifying unique user session.] the appkey was generated using the below function.
function generateRandomString(length) {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let result = '';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
  }


This was sent in the authentication API for which i got the encrypted SEK.

AppKey: OOpqCt5HxiPzkfy5HQuMhggRPkzEbWMe
SEK: yu5fgaDL2QRijlP7YDDOnDfowy3UTRGP0thOGjxUjjdjmjj2BN1CAmrj9glGR2tJ

I want to decrypt this SEK using the same Appkey which was sent via the auth API to encypt this SEK.


function decrypt(sek, appkey) {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ecb', Buffer.from(appkey, 'hex'), null);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(Buffer.from(sek, 'hex'));
  decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
  return decrypted.toString();  }
const decryptedMessage = decrypt(sek, generateRandomString(32));


This is the error I am facing:
Output:
node:internal/crypto/cipher:193
  const ret = this[kHandle].final();
                            ^

Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Decipheriv.final (node:internal/crypto/cipher:193:29)
    at decrypt (/index.js:31:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/index.js:42:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  function: 'EVP_DecryptFinal_ex',
  reason: 'bad decrypt',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_BAD_DECRYPT'
}


for this function:

function encrypt(text, key) {
  const extendedKey = extendKey(key);
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ecb', Buffer.from(extendedKey, 'hex'), null);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
  encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
  return encrypted.toString('hex');
}


This is the error
Output:
node:internal/crypto/cipher:116
    this[kHandle].initiv(cipher, credential, iv, authTagLength);
                  ^

RangeError: Invalid key length
    at Decipheriv.createCipherBase (node:internal/crypto/cipher:116:19)
    at Decipheriv.createCipherWithIV (node:internal/crypto/cipher:135:3)
    at new Decipheriv (node:internal/crypto/cipher:289:3)
    at Object.createDecipheriv (node:crypto:146:10)
    at decrypt (/index.js:35:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/index.js:51:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_CRYPTO_INVALID_KEYLEN'
}




Your SEK looks to be base64 encoded, but you try to hex decode it when you put it in the Buffer.
